# PDF metadata editor - GUI - FEDORA

Tags: fedora, pdf, file-metadata

I can't find a graphical pdf metadata editor for Fedora (Fedora 30). I found "PDFMtEd" which doesn't work in Fedora because it needs "exiftool" but I can't install that.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

[pyExifToolGUI](https://hvdwolf.github.io/pyExifToolGUI)  and [Xnview](https://www.xnview.com/en/) may be suitable; If you are using KDE, also consider [Digikam](https://www.digikam.org/).